# Azure DevOps custom fields - can we make them team or area specific?

Tags: azure-devops, field, customization, azure-boards

I want to have different custom fields for different teams in my Azure Boards.

I see in the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/add-custom-field?view=azure-devops that custom fields for a work item are being set at a process level, i.e. at project level.

Is there a way to make them team-specific and not project-specific? Or at least how to restrict visibility on custom fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that we can not make custom fields team-specific. Here is a suggestion ticket about [Custom fields on team-level](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Custom-fields-on-team-level/803813?space=21&sort=relevance&q=custom%20field%20team%20).

Please create a suggestion ticket in [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion).